# Saving a collection to a database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a database table called UserCommission which i have made an eloquent model for below:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserCommission extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
    protected $table = 'UserCommission';
}
```

Now in my controller I have an alot of information I want to add to that table. I first made it into a collection like below:

```
        $returnData = new Collection();

        foreach ($datePeriod as $key => $date)
        {
            foreach ($consultants as $consultant)
            {
                $year  = (int) $date->format('Y');
                $month = (int) $date->format('n');

                $commission = new UserCommission();

                $commission->userId = $consultant['UserId'];
                $commission->year   = $year;
                $commission->month  = $month;
                $commission->commissionPercentage = Self::getCommissionPercentage($consultant['UserId'], $consultant['CreatedOn'], $consultant['RoleId'], $date);

                $returnData->push($commission);
            }
        }
```

So when I print out return data, it prints out a collection filled with the correct items with their properties to match up with the table fields. I cant find how I would save this to the table though.

I have tried

```
$returnData->save();
```

But thats not a collection function.

Comment: You'll have to foreach through `$returnData` and save each item in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert them all at once, you can bypass the Collection and do this instead:

```
$commissions = []; 

foreach ($datePeriod as $key => $date)
{
    foreach ($consultants as $consultant)
    {
        $year  = (int) $date->format('Y');
        $month = (int) $date->format('n');

        $commissions[] = [
            'userId' => $consultant['UserId'];
            'year' => $year, 
            'month' => $month
            'commissionPercentage' => Self::getCommissionPercentage($consultant['UserId'], $consultant['CreatedOn'], $consultant['RoleId'], $date);
        ]; 
    }
}
```

Since, `insert()` can accept an array of data you want to insert, the following would be now possible:

```
UserCommission::insert($commissions);
```

Comment: Does `create()`accept multiple records?  I always believed you had to do `insert()` when you need more than one...

Comment: You are right, it does not. Not sure why I thought it did. `insert()` should be used instead, like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid having multiple inserts done one after another (hence avoiding database performance issues due to consecutive queries), you can also insert them in one go using `Model::insert()`

See https://implode.io/inf5OO for an example.

as per the comments below, take note that his approach won't fire eloquent events for the inserted records...

Comment: Important note: Doing it this way won't fire any Eloquent model observers you may have on the `UserCommission` model, so if you rely on those, you need to take a different approach.

Comment: true!  you could still insert them like this, and throw an event for the inserted records from your controller.  All depends on how many you are inserting...

Comment: Yeah. Just figured I'd highlight it as I've gotten bit by this caveat myself. :-)

Comment: edited the answer to include that important remark indeed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
$user_commission = new UserCommission;
#Do Stuff
$user_commission->save();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserts

Comment: Would this insert them all at once? or 1 at a time

Comment: I think you have to insert them one at a time.  I've never had to do multiples in Laravel before.

Comment: That's one by one, which is probably not what you want ;-)